# How does GCP Error reporting differentiates errors?

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am trying [@google-cloud/error-reporting npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/error-reporting). I would like to know how Error reporting differentate errors. I often see two different errors being grouped as one error even if they have a different error message and appear at a differente line of code.

Do you have any hints on this?

Here is the simplified code I use for express error handler middleware in App engine standard:

```
import {ErrorReporting} from '@google-cloud/error-reporting';
const GCPerrorReporting = new ErrorReporting();

export default function(error, req, res, next) {
    GCPerrorReporting.report(error); //The error has a message property
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you throw the same HTTP error code?

Comment: Yes! I was throwing 500 HTTP error code during my tests but with different error messages and at different lines of code. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: I would say that because the error code is the same, the error is considered as similar.

Comment: Thank you for your replies @guillaumeblaquiere ! I just did a little test and it seems you are right. That is not very practical because most of the server errors have the 500 http status code.